# How to efficiently represent blobs in binary image with ellipse? | OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, blob, ellipse

I want to represent blobs with oriented ellipse.

I have achieved this with `findContours()` in opencv. But I am thinking in real-time application contours or blob detector, which will perform better.

```
GaussianBlur(im, tempIm, Size(9, 9), 1, 1, BORDER_REFLECT);
findContours(tempIm, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS);
```

Also Blur extends the boundary of the blob, which is not-required.

Input Image

[image: Input image]

Output Image

[image: Output image]

Comment: Try median blur instead GaussianBlur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contours is the outline of an object and [blob detector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html) is an algorithm on top of `findContours`. Blob detector not only finds the boundaries, but also calculates the center and whether or not it matches certain shapes and sizes that you define. It is more heavy than `findContours` and you shouldn't use it if you care for performance and don't need these features.

You can use median blur instead of Gaussian, if you want to keep the image binary and do not extend contours. Also you can use [dilate/erode/open/close operations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) and their combinations to denoise the binary image. These approaches are relatively comparable on binary images and you can test both for best performance and result and choose one for your task.

[Tutorial code here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.7/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html) describes how to represent the found contours with ellipses. `cv::fitEllipse` is used to create an ellipse for a contour. Then you can display it with `cv::ellipse` drawing function.